Most space-efficient way of storing large number of large integers
I have a large number of very large integers (in general, larger than unsigned long long), e.g.
976790216313803691633662
213166167
12361374472474414331778521
74143614714316467475274141141343747437542416477224365045416
...
46247285274316436417475827426432634528582016257012061846140147206
7287516801860168175715895175371357381735188912758511

which I would like to store in a file. What is the most space-efficient method to store them? I have tried several methods, including converting to bytes and storing in an h5 file, storing as .npz using numpy, but the most compression I get is by storing them in plain text and then making a .tar.gz of the file.
Is there a better way (i.e., which would give better compression)? There could be anywhere between 10^4 and 10^12 lines per file.
Edit:
You can produce a minimal reproducible example by running the following in python (which is how the list of numbers is obtained in the first place):
import numpy as np
def generate_int(n):
    return int(str(np.random.randint(1, 10)) + ''.join([str(np.random.randint(0, 10)) for _ in range(n-1)]))
output = [generate_int(np.random.randint(4, 1001)) for _ in range(1000000)]


have you tried pickle?

maybe create a [mre] for benchmarking?

Do you have these values as a list of int in Python? If so, use pickle. You could write the values (as text) to a temporary file then use the ZipFIle and the BZIP2 algorithm for a similar level of compression. However, the latter approach will be much slower than pickle

I have added a short code to reproduce the output I am want to save to file.

Your generate_int function for reproduction takes 20 minutes to complete. Can we replace it with random.randint(1000, 10 ** n) ?

Do you really need it to be the most space efficient? I'd go for a simple gzip compressed text file, with one number per line. Good ratio of size / effort.

@Julien Pickle loads the whole file, doesn't it? With up to 10^12 lines you might get into memory issues.

When generating one number at a time the python random is faster than numpy.  numpy random is better for generating a whole array of numpy dtype values.  If you really want large ints, stay away from numpy.

@ken we can, but then we would be limited to generating numbers within the bounds of np.int64. My method generates arbitrarily large ints, which is the case I am trying to solve.

@John No. Not np.random, but the standard library's random. It is not limited to 64 bits.

Note that realistic numbers generally are not random. In fact, even beyond representation much data has inherent structure that can be used for effective compression. While the theoretical case of perfectly random data is interesting and easy to generalise (and on-topic), if you can describe the actual data better another question specifically on that is likely to give much better results.

Also, note that the example given is not purely random either. 4-digit numbers and 1000-digit numbers appear with the same probability. It is biased towards "small" values.

What ken said. Is your actual data really distributed like your example, with the distribution of digit lengths of each number being uniform? The most efficient compression scheme depends on the actual expected distribution.

@ken I think you mean that it is not uniformly distributed. It is certainly random.

The possible values range from 1000 to 101000-1. Those can be represented with 10 to 3326 bits, always with a leading 1 bit. We will leave off the leading 1, so each number will be represented by 9..3325 bits.
Each set of bits will be preceded by a prefix code for the number of bits. There are 3317 possible bit counts, for which the first 779 will be coded as 11 bits and the remaining 2538 will be coded as 12 bits. The average will be 11.765 bits each. Each will then be followed by 9..3325 bits, averaging 1667 bits.
Your full sequence of one million such randomly and uniformly chosen such numbers would then be coded in 1678765150 bits on average, or 209845644 bytes. (If coding in bytes, the last few bits will be detected as an incomplete 11..12 bit bit-count code, and discarded.)  The total length will vary by about ±0.057% 1σ around those averages.

If we leave the actual values of the numbers out of account and assume perfect entropy, we are left with the following observations based on the sample provided:

All the numbers are unsigned integers.
The largest number can be represented with 215 bits.

We can then envision an encoding scheme that uses 8 bits to express the length of each number, followed by the actual bits of the number.
For the provided sample:
976790216313803691633662
213166167
12361374472474414331778521
74143614714316467475274141141343747437542416477224365045416
46247285274316436417475827426432634528582016257012061846140147206
7287516801860168175715895175371357381735188912758511

We get the following bit lengths:
80
28
84
196
215
173

This adds up to a total of 776 bits. Add to that 48 bits to encode the length of each number (i.e. 6 * 8 bits) to get a total of 824 bits, or 103 bytes.
For comparison:

The above raw bits approach: 103 bytes
Text-based approach using regular gzip compression of file contents: 144 bytes
(cat n | gzip > n.gz)
Text-based approach using tar/gzip compression of file: 249 bytes
(tar -czvf n.tar.gz n)


Could you show an implementation of this? I do now quite understand how it would work.

I'm just answering the "Most space-efficient way of storing large number of large integers" question. Not planning to provide an implementation.

That is ignoring .... Those numbers are way smaller than the one generated by the [mre]. That being said, even with 2 bytes for the size (which is the absolute maximum for the mre code: 1000 base 10 digits  at most, so 3322 bits at most), and even by rounding the integer bits to upper 8, to ease implementation, that is still only 111 bytes, for this example.

Besides, if we store bits by packet of 8 (so 792 bits instead of 776), there is no need to store the number of bits: only the number of bytes. In which case maximum value of size is not "3322 bits" but "416 bytes". It doesn't help for this MRE, but with other parameters...

@chrslg Yes, I ignored the ... because I assumed it to be used as an indicator of "more data". The minimal reproducible example did not exist when I wrote my answer. Again: I answered the question of the "most space-efficient way of storing..." based on the data available at the time. Not the most practical way, not the easiest-to-implement way, not the can-be-extrapolated-to-all-kinds-of-data-unknown-at-the-time-of-writing way.

That being said, just adding the required number of bits to be able to express the maximum bit length, this is probably still the most efficient answer. Storing bytes will net you an average loss of 4 bits per number, while you only need 3 extra bits (2^3=8) to express bit length instead of byte length.

Yes, I surmised that your answer was probably before the [mre] (I did not investigate the edit date to be sure). And I understand that your answer is theoretical, counting entropy. Normally, if distribution of data is like the MRE, it should be optimal entropy-wise, since size of numbers follow a uniform law, so storing the size and the bits should be optimal (if bᵢ is the ith bit of your representation, then ℙ(bᵢ=1) is ½, and all bᵢ are independent — roughly. So, theoretically, impossible to do better than your representation, at least as long as distribution of numbers are as in MRE)

@chrslg No, it is certainly possible to do better. E.g. leaving off the leading 1 bit from every number. There's a million bits right there. You can represent the length as a prefix code instead of 16 bits, saving more than four million bits.

@RobbyCornelissen thank you for the answer, I appreciate that I didn't ask about implementation (I will make a separate question). I am indeed looking for the most space-efficient way as this is meant for long-term storage.

You could mimick utf-8 way to represent the length, sure. But in MRE, length is distributed with uniform law. So, normally, the 16 bits (well, 14, if we want to be accurate) are almost optimal entropy-wise (not exactly because 4096 is not 3322). But, I get the point for the first bit. Indeed, that one does not agree with ℙ(bᵢ=1)=½.

@chrslg 12. 4096 is 12 bits. If you want to be accurate.

@MarkAdler: ouch. I am loosing my ability to count in base 2 :( (in my defense, in the same time, I was answering a question about float64 representation, in which result was mantissa/16384, hence the 14 bits in my head)
